Why aren't sites like Mapgenie an infringement of intellectual property?
The site mapgenie.io provides interactive maps of video game universes with location names, as well as locations of items etc of these games. Can sites like this exist without licensing the material?

Fair Use/Dealing - Exceptions from Copyright
Most jurisdictions have some sort of right to cite or use someone else's work in a limited fashion, such as to reference the work, comment on it or make fun of it. The purpose and nature of the use, as well as the amount of the used work are substantial facts in the determination if something falls under the exception or not.
Acting could anger the fans!
Let me draw a reference to a real series of cases from the past: Once upon a time there was an indie studio called Tactical Studies Rules and they went big. After selling like hotcake in the 70s, the owners spent a lot of money badly in the early 80s and they were desperate for cash. Mr. Gygax hired Lorraine Williams to head the company... and she bought out the other shareholders, and then Mr. Gygax himself. She was a very centralized manager, and in the early 90s, the company wasn't doing the best. And then the internet came around in the mid-90s, it strikes 1994.
Fans of the games published by TSR made websites and Williams saw those freely available sites with rules and modules as a danger to their IP. She had her legal team send Cease and Desist to any page about any RPG they could find the owner from, in an attempt to bully those sites off the internet - no matter if their claims had merit, or if the site was about any IP they owned at all. Shortly after, messageboards called them T$R, and people sought other games than TSR products. By threatening to sue their fans, they lost many of their fans in the worst times... and had to close shop in 1997 and were sold to Wizards of the Coast, the inventors of the Trading Card Game.

One could also argue that a site like mapgenie.io only provides value to people who have access to the actual game the maps belong to. So mapgenie is not taking any revenue from the game owner (unless the game owner sells the game and a similar map to the game as separate items).

@quarague that is usually not an argument available under copyright law on its own, but would be reflected in the nature and use of the material.

@Trish That wouldn't be part of the legal analysis, but it would be part of the business analysis on the part of the rights holders. Sites like this help drive online discussion of the game, which helps drive sales, so there's a significant cost to consider even before getting into the question of goodwill.

true, though goodwill by hosing the content for the fans for free and handing the info needed can go leagues... see... EU4.
